# Add missing rows to data.table according to multiple keyed columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table, cross-join

I have a `data.table` object that contains multiple columns that specify unique cases.  In the small example below, the variables "`name`", "`job`", and "`sex`" specify the unique IDs.  I would like to add missing rows so that each each case has a row for each possible instance of another variable, "`from`" (similar to `expand.grid`).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.table(name = c("john","john","john","john","mary","chris","chris","chris"),
                 job = c("teacher","teacher","teacher","teacher","police","lawyer","lawyer","doctor"),
                 sex = c("male","male","male","male","female","female","male","male"),
                 from = c("NYT","USAT","BG","TIME","USAT","BG","NYT","NYT"),
                 score = rnorm(8))

setkeyv(mydata, cols=c("name","job","sex"))

mydata[CJ(unique(name, job, sex), unique(from))]
```

Here's the current data.table object:

```
> mydata
    name     job    sex from      score
1:  john teacher   male  NYT -0.6264538
2:  john teacher   male USAT  0.1836433
3:  john teacher   male   BG -0.8356286
4:  john teacher   male TIME  1.5952808
5:  mary  police female USAT  0.3295078
6: chris  lawyer female   BG -0.8204684
7: chris  lawyer   male  NYT  0.4874291
8: chris  doctor   male  NYT  0.7383247
```

Here's the result I'd like:

```
> mydata
     name     job    sex from      score
1:   john teacher   male  NYT -0.6264538
2:   john teacher   male USAT  0.1836433
3:   john teacher   male   BG -0.8356286
4:   john teacher   male TIME  1.5952808
5:   mary  police female  NYT  NA
6:   mary  police female USAT  0.3295078
7:   mary  police female   BG  NA
8:   mary  police female TIME  NA
9:  chris  lawyer female  NYT -NA
10: chris  lawyer female USAT -NA
11: chris  lawyer female   BG -0.8204684
12: chris  lawyer female TIME -NA
13: chris  lawyer   male  NYT  0.4874291
14: chris  lawyer   male USAT  NA
15: chris  lawyer   male   BG  NA
16: chris  lawyer   male TIME  NA
17: chris  doctor   male  NYT  0.7383247
18: chris  doctor   male USAT  NA
19: chris  doctor   male   BG  NA
20: chris  doctor   male TIME  NA
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
setkeyv(mydata, cols=c("name","job","sex"))
mydata[CJ(unique(name, job, sex), unique(from))]
```

But I receive the following error and adding fromLast=TRUE (or FALSE) does not give me the right solution:

```
Error in unique.default(name, job, sex) : 
  'fromLast' must be TRUE or FALSE
```

Here are the relevant answers I've come across (but none appears to deal with multiple keyed columns):
[add missing rows to a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462405/add-missing-rows-to-a-data-table)

[Efficiently inserting default missing rows in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518505/efficiently-inserting-default-missing-rows-in-a-data-table)

[Fastest way to add rows for missing values in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of possibilities are here - https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/814

```
CJ.dt = function(...) {
  rows = do.call(CJ, lapply(list(...), function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) seq_len(nrow(x)) else seq_along(x)));
  do.call(data.table, Map(function(x, y) x[y], list(...), rows))
}

setkey(mydata, name, job, sex, from)

mydata[CJ.dt(unique(data.table(name, job, sex)), unique(from))]
#     name     job    sex from      score
# 1: chris  doctor   male  NYT  0.7383247
# 2: chris  doctor   male   BG         NA
# 3: chris  doctor   male TIME         NA
# 4: chris  doctor   male USAT         NA
# 5: chris  lawyer female  NYT         NA
# 6: chris  lawyer female   BG -0.8204684
# 7: chris  lawyer female TIME         NA
# 8: chris  lawyer female USAT         NA
# 9: chris  lawyer   male  NYT  0.4874291
#10: chris  lawyer   male   BG         NA
#11: chris  lawyer   male TIME         NA
#12: chris  lawyer   male USAT         NA
#13:  john teacher   male  NYT -0.6264538
#14:  john teacher   male   BG -0.8356286
#15:  john teacher   male TIME  1.5952808
#16:  john teacher   male USAT  0.1836433
#17:  mary  police female  NYT         NA
#18:  mary  police female   BG         NA
#19:  mary  police female TIME         NA
#20:  mary  police female USAT  0.3295078
```

Answer (score 4):

The dev version of tidyr now has an elegant way to do this because the `expand()` function now supports nesting and crossing:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata <- data_frame(
  name = c("john","john","john","john","mary","chris","chris","chris"),
  job = c("teacher","teacher","teacher","teacher","police","lawyer","lawyer","doctor"),
  sex = c("male","male","male","male","female","female","male","male"),
  from = c("NYT","USAT","BG","TIME","USAT","BG","NYT","NYT"),
  score = rnorm(8)
)

mydata %>% 
  expand(c(name, job, sex), from) %>% 
  left_join(mydata)

#> Joining by: c("name", "job", "sex", "from")
#> Source: local data frame [20 x 5]
#> 
#>     name     job    sex from      score
#> 1  chris  doctor   male   BG         NA
#> 2  chris  doctor   male  NYT  0.5448206
#> 3  chris  doctor   male TIME         NA
#> 4  chris  doctor   male USAT         NA
#> 5  chris  lawyer female   BG  1.2015173
#> 6  chris  lawyer female  NYT         NA
#> 7  chris  lawyer female TIME         NA
#> 8  chris  lawyer female USAT         NA
#> 9  chris  lawyer   male   BG         NA
#> 10 chris  lawyer   male  NYT -1.0930237
#> 11 chris  lawyer   male TIME         NA
#> 12 chris  lawyer   male USAT         NA
#> 13  john teacher   male   BG  1.1345461
#> 14  john teacher   male  NYT  1.3032946
#> 15  john teacher   male TIME  2.4901830
#> 16  john teacher   male USAT -1.6449096
#> 17  mary  police female   BG         NA
#> 18  mary  police female  NYT         NA
#> 19  mary  police female TIME         NA
#> 20  mary  police female USAT -0.2443080
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to `paste` the columns `name`, `job`, and `sex` together, get the `unique` values, and then do `CJ` with the `unique` values of `from`.  After that, use `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)` to split the `pasted` column back to three columns, rename those columns with `setnames`, and `join` with `mydata` after setting the `key`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
mydata1 <- setnames(cSplit(mydata[,CJ(unique(paste(name, job, sex)), 
            from=unique(from))], 'V1', ' '), 2:4, c('name', 'job', 'sex'))[,
                     c(2:4,1)]
setkeyv(mydata, cols=colnames(mydata)[1:4])
mydata[mydata1]
#      name     job    sex from      score
#1: chris  doctor   male   BG         NA
#2: chris  doctor   male  NYT  0.7383247
#3: chris  doctor   male TIME         NA
#4: chris  doctor   male USAT         NA
#5: chris  lawyer female   BG -0.8204684
#6: chris  lawyer female  NYT         NA
#7: chris  lawyer female TIME         NA
#8: chris  lawyer female USAT         NA
#9: chris  lawyer   male   BG         NA
#10: chris  lawyer   male  NYT  0.4874291
#11: chris  lawyer   male TIME         NA
#12: chris  lawyer   male USAT         NA
#13:  john teacher   male   BG -0.8356286
#14:  john teacher   male  NYT -0.6264538
#15:  john teacher   male TIME  1.5952808
#16:  john teacher   male USAT  0.1836433
#17:  mary  police female   BG         NA
#18:  mary  police female  NYT         NA
#19:  mary  police female TIME         NA
#20:  mary  police female USAT  0.3295078
```

Comment: Pretty intense. Is that 2:4 for column selection?

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, to rename those columns using `setnames`