# Join each row with each other row

Tags: r, join, data.table

Assume that we have a simple data table:

```
d <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c("A","B","C"))
```

It's content is:

```
   a b
1: 1 A
2: 2 B
3: 3 C
```

Now, I want to join/merge each row of the data table with each other row. The result should look like this:

```
   a b c d
1: 1 A 1 A
2: 1 A 2 B
3: 1 A 3 C
4: 2 B 1 A
5: 2 B 2 B
6: 2 B 3 C
7: 3 C 1 A
8: 3 C 2 B
9: 3 C 3 C
```

So, each row is basically cbind'ed with the whole data table.
What is the most efficient way to do this? Could this be done only using data.table syntax?

Thank you!

Edit:
The CJ-Method of data.table does build a cartesion product but only for vectors, not tables.

Comment: merge is the most efficient way (cartesian product)

Comment: `d[, .(c = d$a, d = d$b), by = .(a, b)]`?

Comment: r u looking for cross joining of data.tables? if yes, pls see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386618/1989480

Comment: @chinsoon12 OP said at the end of the question that `CJ` isn't giving the desired solution ....

Comment: @Jaap indeed data.table::CJ only applies to **vectors** and the link I posted is for **tables**

Comment: Another dupe candidate similar to chinsoon's: Jan's CJ.dt https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347397

Answer (score 5):

Three possible solutions:

```
# one
d[, .(c = d$a, d = d$b), by = .(a, b)]

# two
d[, setnames(d, c("c","d")), by = .(a, b)]

# three
d[, setNames(as.list(d), c("c","d")), by = .(a, b)]
```

which both give:

> ```
>    a b c d
> 1: 1 A 1 A
> 2: 1 A 2 B
> 3: 1 A 3 C
> 4: 2 B 1 A
> 5: 2 B 2 B
> 6: 2 B 3 C
> 7: 3 C 1 A
> 8: 3 C 2 B
> 9: 3 C 3 C
> ```

The second option will also change the column names of the original data.table `d`. If you don't want that, you adapt the second option to:

```
d[, setnames(copy(d), c("c","d")), by = .(a, b)]
```

---

Additionaly (including my comment under [bJust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108681/2204410)) you can also use `merge`, but that only works on `data.table`'s when explicitly calling the `data.frame`-method:

```
merge.data.frame(d, d, by = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is their also a convenient solution of the number of columns is large?

Comment: @Julian It that case you can use solution two or three, e.g.: `d[, setnames(copy(d), paste0(names(d),"_2")), by = .(a, b)]` or `d[, setnames(copy(d), paste0("V",1:ncol(d))), by = .(a, b)]`

Answer (score 0):

My naive solution using data.frame (if that is an alternative), not data.table:

```
merge(d,d,by=NULL)
```

by=NULL ensures to get all combinations

Comment: That doesn't work on [tag:data.table]'s. On [tag:data.table]'s you should explicitly call the dataframe method: `merge.data.frame(d, d, by = NULL)`