# Manipulating a data table for Poisson regression: adding rows of zeros and lagging variables

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-manipulation, poisson

I am working with a large dataset of a fishing fleet and I need to format it for a poisson regression and other count models. See below for a subset of the data. The count variable is 'days'. p1:p3 are indicator variables for port group and f1:f4 are indicator variables for other fishing activity.

```
yr   week   id  days rev    p1  p2 p3   f1  f2  f3  f4
2016    3   1   1   5568.3  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    4   1   3   8869.53 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    5   1   2   12025.8 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    6   1   2   9126.6  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    7   1   3   4415.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    8   1   2   11586.6 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    10  1   1   2144.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    11  1   1   2183.25 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    14  1   2   4998    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    15  1   3   117     0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    1   2   4   12743.3 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    2   2   2   7473.48 0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2016    5   2   2   8885.52 0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2016    7   2   1   15330.6 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    8   2   2   3763.8  0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    9   2   1   2274.05 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
```

These rows only represent active weeks but I need to incorporate each vessel's inactive weeks. For example, for id=1, in year (yr) 2016 I need to add rows that start at week=1, and then rows for weeks 9,12, and 13. These rows will need to maintain the same information in the dummy categories (these don't change by yr), and have zeros in the 'days' column. I don't need to add rows after the last value of 'week' for that year and vessel.

This is where things get really complicated:

In the revenue (rev) column for these newly created rows I need to add the average revenue for that week and year for all vessels that share the same port group (p1:p3).

Finally, I need to add a new column of lagged revenues. For each row, the value for lagged revenue should be the value in the 'rev' column for the previous week for that vessel in that year.

The value for week 1 for each vessel should be the average of the first 2 weeks of revenue for that vessel in that year.

This task blows my data manipulation skills to smithereens and banging my head against the wall is starting to hurt. Any suggestions would be well appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Start here and let us know how far that gets you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462405/add-missing-rows-to-a-data-table

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been trying to figure this out over the last several hours and it seems that CJ may not be what I need? I am not trying to add rows for every possible value of week, rather the values of week (starting at week=1) that are missing (up to the maximum value of week for each id and season).

Comment: I may have thought of a way to attack this in a combination of excel and access but I am really trying to get away from those familiar fallbacks. In any case I will report back if I find a solution...

Comment: Actually have not made progress in excel/access either. It's surprising that this issue has not manifested itself more often on the stats forums!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg, and https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802241/user2802241, the issue has been solved. You can see a post on the adding rows part at:
[Adding rows to a data.table according to column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673618/adding-rows-to-a-data-table-according-to-column-values)

```
test<-data.frame(DT %>% 
  group_by(yr, id) %>% 
  complete(week = 1:max(week)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(days = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(yr, id) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = T))), p1:f4))

    poisson<-data.table(test)
    setkey(poisson,yr,id,week)

    avrev<-poisson[,.(avrev = mean(rev,na.rm=T)),by=.(p1,p2,[p3,week,yr)]
    avrev<-transform(avrev,xyz=interaction(p1,p2,p3,week,yr,sep=''))
    poisson<-transform(poisson,xyz=interaction(tier200,tier300,tier500,week,yr,sep=''))
    poisson<-transform(poisson,uniqueid=interaction(drvid,season,sep=''))

    poisson$rev[is.na(poisson$rev)]<- avrev$avrev[match(poisson$xyz[is.na(poisson$rev)],avrev$xyz)]

    poisson[, lagrev:=c(rev[1], rev[-.N]), by=uniqueid]
```

I'm sure there is a much nicer and neater way to accomplish the task but this works. David Arenburg also posted an answer in the comments section that utilizes data.table to create the new rows- see the other post.

Answer (score 0):

To get the average of revenue by week, year, p1, p2, and p3 just use the aggregate function:

`average_rev <- aggregate(rev~week+year+p1+p2+p3, data=your_dataframe, FUN=mean)`

To add a new column of lagged revenues:

`your_dataframe$lagged_rev <- c(NA, your_dataframe$rev[1:(nrow(_your_dataframe)-1)])`

To get average rev for the last two weeks:

`your_dataframe$avg_rev <- rowMeans(your_dataframe[,c('rev','lagged_rev')])`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. The first part works to calculate average revenue, but the first task I am trying to undertake is to add new rows to populate with the average revenues.

Comment: The method for lagged revenues does not work as when I get to the end of a 'year' the first value for the next year is just the last value of the previous year which is not what I need. The data are not balanced!

Comment: For the lagged values, you can split your data for all years so that you have multiple datasets for each year and then do the lagged analysis. This way you won't get previous years' revenue when you do the lagged analysis.

Comment: To merge your original dataframe with `average_rev`, just use the merge function. First you may need to rename the variable for average revenue in `average_rev`. Something like:
`names(average_rev)[6] <- 'avgrev'` then:
`newdf <- merge(your_dataframe, average_rev)`

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Bansal, I am still stuck on the adding new rows issue. I'm surprised this isn't a more common issue.

Comment: You can add rows using the `rbind` function. Good luck!