# Adding rows to a data.table according to column values

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am working with a large dataset and I need to add rows to it. This issue was raised in another question but I am separating this particular issue from other questions in the original question. I'm fairly new to SO so please let me know if this is not a 'done' thing.

Data example:

```
yr   week   id  days rev    p1  p2 p3   f1  f2  f3  f4
2016    3   1   1   5568.3  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    4   1   3   8869.53 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    5   1   2   12025.8 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    6   1   2   9126.6  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    7   1   3   4415.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    8   1   2   11586.6 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    10  1   1   2144.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    11  1   1   2183.25 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    14  1   2   4998    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    15  1   3   117     0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    1   2   4   12743.3 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    2   2   2   7473.48 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    5   2   2   8885.52 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    7   2   1   15330.6 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    8   2   2   3763.8  0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    9   2   1   2274.05 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
```

For each combination of id and yr there are several rows of data corresponding to week. The p1:p3 and f1:f4 columns are id/yr invariant, rev varies with week.

For each combination of yr/id there is a maximum value for week. What I want to do is to add missing rows starting from one for week=1, up to the maximum value for that yr/id combination.

I would like to end up with:

```
yr  week    id  days    rev p1  p2  p3  f1  f2  f3  f4
2016    1   1   0   NA      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    2   1   0   NA      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    3   1   1   5568.3  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    4   1   3   8869.53 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    5   1   2   12025.8 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    6   1   2   9126.6  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    7   1   3   4415.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    8   1   2   11586.6 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    9   1   0   NA      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    10  1   1   2144.4  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    11  1   1   2183.25 0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    12  1   0   NA      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    13  1   0   NA      0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    14  1   2   4998    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    15  1   3   117     0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016    1   2   4   12743.3 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    2   2   2   7473.48 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    3   2   0   NA      0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    4   2   0   NA      0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    5   2   2   8885.52 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    6   2   0   NA      0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    7   2   1   15330.6 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    8   2   2   3763.8  0   0   1   1   1   0   0
2016    9   2   1   2274.05 0   0   1   1   1   0   0
```

I have tried using CJ from the data.table package but the issue is that the join is different for each id/season group. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You need to find the max value for each year/id first, then find the missing week numbers, and then add new rows for these missing weeks.

Comment: First part I have done using: 
maxwk<-DT[,.(week.max = max(week)),by=.(yr,id)]

Comment: I think a general plan of action for the second part of the suggestion would be to generate a column of values for week for each yr/id combination, then figure out which ones are missing from the original data set, then create the new rows?

Comment: Try `DT[, .SD[match(1:max(week), week)], by = .(yr, id)]` if your data set called `DT`.

Comment: For the second part I guess something like:length<-sequence(maxwk$week.max)

Comment: David- this seems so simple but works really well. Incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping with `dplyr` (v0.4.3) and the `complete` function from `tidyr` (v0.4.1) should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(yr, id) %>% 
  complete(week = 1:max(week)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(days = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(yr, id) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = T))), p1:f4)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am having some trouble following your code- I am a dplyr newbie. The code appears to work apart from some NAs appear in the yr, id, and rev columns, and the values for p1:p3 and f1:f4 are "Nan".

Comment: What versions of dplyr and tidyr are you using? Works for me using dplyr 0.4.3 and tidyr 0.4.1.

Comment: I just installed the packages from CRAN so I assume the newest versions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check versions of packages?

Comment: It's funny- in your code above 'df' was a data.table. I tried your code without making df a data.table (just a data.frame) and I don't have the issue with the NAs and NaNs.....